# What good is virtual in a class?

Tags: c++, oop, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)

For example i have:

```
class A {
    private: 
        int i; 
        int j; 

    public: 
        void k (int l, int m) { i=l; j=m; } 
        virtual int n (void); 
};

class B : public A { 
    public: 
        int n (void);
};
```

What good is this virtual ?

Comment: This is very lazy formatting. Indent your code by four spaces, and lay it out properly.

Comment: Or highlight the code and use the "101010" button.

Comment: This must be a massive duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It's to induce polymorphic behaviour, which means that a single contract can be used by a client to invoke different behaviours, without the client having to know about every possible behaviour.

```
A* a = new B();
a->n(); // Will call B::n();
```

As a more concrete example, here some fairly stereotypical code:

```
struct Shape {
    GLfloat transform_[4][4];

    void render() const {
        glPushMatrix();
        glMultMatrixf(&transform_[0][0]);
        draw();
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

struct Line : public Shape {
    GLfloat x1, y1, x2, y2;

    void draw() {
        glBegin();
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glEnd();
    }
};

struct Square : public Shape {
    GLfloat size;

    void draw() {
        GLfloat f = size/2;
        glBegin();
        glVertex2f(-f, -f);
        glVertex2f( f, -f);
        glVertex2f( f,  f);
        glVertex2f(-f,  f);
        glVertex2f(-f, -f);
        glEnd();
    }
};

void renderShapes(Shape* shapes, int nShapes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nShapes; ++i) {
        shapes[i]->render();
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: The above code is neither correct nor complete, and is certainly not to be held up as an example of good graphics code. It's just to illustrate when virtual functions are useful.

Comment: Don't listen to this guy, he's just trying to confuse you.

Comment: @Noah: Are you talking about Marcelo, or some other comment that's since been deleted?

Comment: So that means i can be a mechanic and a policeman at the same time ?

Comment: @tdp This is programming, you make the rule, you choose to make sense or not

Comment: -1: That code is more stereotypical than typical.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the Chess Game as an example for this:

```
class ChessPiece
{
    public:
       virtual int Move() = 0;
};
class Queen: public ChessPiece
{
    public:
       virtual int Move() { /* STUFF */ }
};

bool AICode()
{
    int bestMove = 0;
    foreach(ChessPiece* loop = board.Pieces().begin(); loop != board.Pieces().end(); ++loop)
    {
        bestMove = max(bestMove, loop->Move());
    }
 }
```

The AICode() does not need to know which piece it is looking at.
All it does is ask the piece to see what its best move is. The virtual dispatch mechanism will work out the type of piece and call the correct Move() method.

Comment: So that means it is always going back up to the main class ?

Comment: @tdp: Yes. Even though the pointer loop is a ChessPiece pointer, because the Move() method is virtual it will always go back to the correct derived type and use that version of the Move() method. ie Queen::Move() or Castle::Move() or Knight::Move()  etc

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to this excellent SO page about [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism).