# Difference between virtual and pure virtual function?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)

what is the exact difference b/w **virtual function**  and **pure virtual function** and where should we use these functions in which situation?

Answer (score 2):

A pure virtual function is one that is declared like this:

```
class Foo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

`bar` is a pure virtual member of `Foo`. It has no implementation (hence `= 0`), and cannot be called. Any class that inherits from `Foo` *must* provide an implementation for `bar`. That is the only difference: The parent class has no implementation for the pure virtual, so derived classes must provide it. (There's an exception to this, but it's rarely used.)

Otherwise, it works exactly the same way. Given:

```
class Baz : public Foo {
    virtual void bar() {}
};
```

Any instance of `Baz` can be accessed with a pointer of type `Foo*` and `Baz::bar` will be called. If `Foo::bar` is pure virtual, then `Foo` cannot be instantiated, and calls to `Foo::bar` will be errors. If `Foo::bar` is *not* pure, then the implementation provided for `Foo::bar` will be called for instances of `Foo` and `Baz::bar` will be called for instances of `Baz`, even if it's through a `Foo*`.

(Pure virtuals can also have implementations so that, for example, `Baz::bar` can call `Foo::bar`, but this is uncommon.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Virtual Function have a function body.
2. Overloaded can be done by the Vartual Function.
3. It is define as: Virtual int runFun();

while

1. Pure Vartual Function have on function body.
2. Overloaded is must in Pure Vartual function.
3. It is define as: Virtual int runFun()=0;