# inheritance of abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I hav a base class which is abstract. I am inheritting a new class from the abstract base which i could not instantiate an object. The reason the compiler tells is that

`cannot allocate an object of abstract type`

Is there any way to overcome this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> cannot allocate an object of abstract type

This indicates you've not implemented all the ***pure*** `virtual` functions in the derived class. So first, implement all the pure virtual functions, then create instance of this class.

You cannot create instances of class which has even a single **pure** `virtual` function!

Remember, **pure** virtual functions are those which are assigned with zero ([C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)), as

```
class sample
{
public:
     virtual void f(); //virtual function
     virtual void g()=0; //pure virtual function
};
```

Here only `g()` is pure virtual function! This makes `sample` an [abstract class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr142.htm), and if the derived class doesn't define `g()`,  it would also become an abstract class. You cannot create instance of any of these class, as both of them are abstract!

Comment: ...that has not been overridden in some derived class.