# What does the virtual keyword mean when overriding a method?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

What does the keyword **virtual** do when overriding a method? I'm not using it and everything works fine.

Does every compiler behave the same in this regard?

Should I use it or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)

Comment: @Harald: Nope. Different topic.

Comment: But i'm asking about usage of that keyword. Not about abstract virtual method.

Comment: Virtual keyword in derived class is optional but it's better to skip it. Otherwise, if you have a lot of derived classes and you want to make one of the inherited methods virtual, you would have to add virtual keyword in all of these derived classes to this method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot override a member function without it.

You can only *hide* one.

```
struct Base {
   void foo() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
   void foo() {}
};
```

`Derived::foo` does *not* override `Base::foo`; it simply *hides* it because it has the same name, such that the following:

```
Derived d;
d.foo();
```

invokes `Derived::foo`.

**`virtual`** enables polymorphism such that you *actually* override functions:

```
struct Base {
   virtual void foo() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
   virtual void foo() {} // * second `virtual` is optional, but clearest
};

Derived d;
Base& b = d;
b.foo();
```

This invokes `Derived::foo`, because this now *overrides* `Base::foo` — your object is polymorphic.

(You also *have* to use references or pointers for this, due to [the slicing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).)

---

- `Derived::foo` doesn't need to repeat the `virtual` keyword because `Base::foo` has already used it. This is guaranteed by the standard, and you can rely on it. However, some think it best to keep that in for clarity.

Comment: I know that virtual is necessary when declaring method that can be overridden. I've asked about using this keyword when overriding method, not declaring.

Comment: @Miro: I don't follow. You override a function by declaring another one that overrides it. Either way, at the very least my final paragraph answers your question.

Answer (score 8):

A `virtual` method in the base class will cascade through the hierarchy, making every subclass method with the same signature also `virtual`.

```
class Base{
public:
  virtual void foo(){}
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
public:
  virtual void foo(){} // fine, but 'virtual' is no needed
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
public:
  void foo(){} // also fine, implicitly 'virtual'
};
```

I'd recommend writing the `virtual` though, if for documentation purpose only.

Answer (score 6):

When a function is virtual, it remains virtual throughout the hierarchy, whether or not you explicitly specify each time that it is virtual. When overriding a method, use virtual in order to be more explicit - no other difference :)

```
class A
{
    virtual void f() 
    {
      /*...*/
    };
};

class B:public A;
{
    virtual void f()  //same as just void f()
    {
        /*...*/
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Light Races answer, maybe this will help some people to see what it is doing.

```
struct Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        printf_s("Base::foo\n");
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void foo() {
        printf_s("Derived::foo\n");
    }
};

struct BaseVirtual {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        printf_s("BaseVirtual::foo\n");
    }
};

struct DerivedVirtual : BaseVirtual {
    virtual void foo() {
        printf_s("DerivedVirtual::foo\n");
    } 
};

Derived d;
d.foo(); // Outputs: Derived::foo

Base& b = d;
b.foo(); // Outputs: Base::foo

DerivedVirtual d2;
d2.foo(); // Outputs: DerivedVirtual::foo

BaseVirtual& b2 = d2;
b2.foo(); // Outputs: DerivedVirtual::foo
```