# return "new static" vs return "$this"

Tags: php, laravel

I saw a class in Laravel where "new static()" is being called to create object chaining as opposed to "return $this" which is what i'm familiar with seeing.

Does anyone know why this approach is taken and is there a term for it?
file:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Stringable.php
```

```
class Stringable implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value = '')
    {
        $this->value = (string) $value;
    }

    public function camel()
    {
        return new static(Str::camel($this->value)); // <-- why not "return $this;" instead?
    }
}
```

Trying to understand the approach.

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static

Comment: @xenooooo The link you shared seems to be about something else. I'm wondering why he's using this approach when usually you can return $this pointer to the already created object.

Comment: they don't want to return the current object they want to return a new instance containing the transformed string

Comment: @lagbox Why though? Both approaches achieve the same thing but creating a new object will cause more load on the server.

Comment: Laravel takes this approach with other things too. Collections methods rarely mutate the original collection.

Comment: @IGP I've heard something similar as well. I wonder what the benefit is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why return new static? (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460592/why-return-new-static-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa No it doesn't. It's on a different topic.

Comment: @KGG No it doesn't.

Comment: @IGP your answer seems close to what this could be. Am looking into it. https://blog.sapegin.me/all/avoid-mutation/

Comment: @IGP Your answer was the closest to being correct. If you create a reply I'll accept the answer but link an article in your answer. This could help other people.

Answer (score 1):

> This is an alternative way of `return $this;` ***but is used not just to return the object. It modifies the object before its returns***.

---

In detail, `new static()` is used to create an object of the same class. In your `Stringable` class. So when you use it in your code `__construct` method will call automatically.

Example

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function add($value)
    {
        $this->value += $value;

        return new static($this->value);
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass(5); # retuns 5 -> Via __construct init
$obj2 = $obj->add(10); # retuns 15 -> Via __construct initiated value + New value
```