# Toggle Switch in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to use an element which is the equivalent of [Android Switches](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/switches.html) in Qt. I have found a ToggleSwitch in QML, but nothing in the actual C++ Qt libs. Am I just missing something or will I have to reimplement this widget myself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@piccy's suggestion is what I've done for such a toggle switch previously. With a few tweaks tho.

We had to emulate the behaviours similar to the iOS on/off switches. Meaning you needed a gradual movement which you won't have with slider being with a limit of 0-1 without external animations.

Hence what I did was set the value range for the slider to be the same as the max width of the slider.

Then connect the slider released signal and check if the value is less than half the maximum and if so set slider value to 0 else slider value to max.

This will give you a good drag effect and clip to extremes when you release the mouse.

If you want the slider to just toggle when clicked on the other side without any drag connect the slider value changed signal and check the new value to be closer to either extreme and set it as the slider value *if the slider is not in its down state*.  Do not change slider value if slider is down since you might then break the previous drag motion.

Comment: Awesome man! Nice "snap to ends" effects is achieved by the trick you shared here! I've added the code for the same so that people can understand it better and well.

Answer (score 51):

Here is an example:

`switch.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <QtWidgets>

class Switch : public QAbstractButton {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int offset READ offset WRITE setOffset)
    Q_PROPERTY(QBrush brush READ brush WRITE setBrush)

public:
    Switch(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    Switch(const QBrush& brush, QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    QSize sizeHint() const override;

    QBrush brush() const {
        return _brush;
    }
    void setBrush(const QBrush &brsh) {
        _brush = brsh;
    }

    int offset() const {
        return _x;
    }
    void setOffset(int o) {
        _x = o;
        update();
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) override;
    void enterEvent(QEvent*) override;

private:
    bool _switch;
    qreal _opacity;
    int _x, _y, _height, _margin;
    QBrush _thumb, _track, _brush;
    QPropertyAnimation *_anim = nullptr;
};
```

`switch.cpp`:

```
Switch::Switch(QWidget *parent) : QAbstractButton(parent),
_height(16),
_opacity(0.000),
_switch(false),
_margin(3),
_thumb("#d5d5d5"),
_anim(new QPropertyAnimation(this, "offset", this))
{
    setOffset(_height / 2);
    _y = _height / 2;
    setBrush(QColor("#009688"));
}

Switch::Switch(const QBrush &brush, QWidget *parent) : QAbstractButton(parent),
_height(16),
_switch(false),
_opacity(0.000),
_margin(3),
_thumb("#d5d5d5"),
_anim(new QPropertyAnimation(this, "offset", this))
{
    setOffset(_height / 2);
    _y = _height / 2;
    setBrush(brush);
}

void Switch::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    if (isEnabled()) {
        p.setBrush(_switch ? brush() : Qt::black);
        p.setOpacity(_switch ? 0.5 : 0.38);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        p.drawRoundedRect(QRect(_margin, _margin, width() - 2 * _margin, height() - 2 * _margin), 8.0, 8.0);
        p.setBrush(_thumb);
        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        p.drawEllipse(QRectF(offset() - (_height / 2), _y - (_height / 2), height(), height()));
    } else {
        p.setBrush(Qt::black);
        p.setOpacity(0.12);
        p.drawRoundedRect(QRect(_margin, _margin, width() - 2 * _margin, height() - 2 * _margin), 8.0, 8.0);
        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        p.setBrush(QColor("#BDBDBD"));
        p.drawEllipse(QRectF(offset() - (_height / 2), _y - (_height / 2), height(), height()));
    }
}

void Switch::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (e->button() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        _switch = _switch ? false : true;
        _thumb = _switch ? _brush : QBrush("#d5d5d5");
        if (_switch) {
            _anim->setStartValue(_height / 2);
            _anim->setEndValue(width() - _height);
            _anim->setDuration(120);
            _anim->start();
        } else {
            _anim->setStartValue(offset());
            _anim->setEndValue(_height / 2);
            _anim->setDuration(120);
            _anim->start();
        }
    }
    QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}

void Switch::enterEvent(QEvent *e) {
    setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    QAbstractButton::enterEvent(e);
}

QSize Switch::sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(2 * (_height + _margin), _height + 2 * _margin);
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "switch.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
        widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        QHBoxLayout layout;
        widget->setLayout(&layout);
        Switch *_switch = new Switch;
        Switch *_switch2 = new Switch;
        _switch2->setDisabled(true);
        layout.addWidget(_switch);
        layout.addWidget(_switch2);
        widget->show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

[image]

## Update Aug 20'18

**New Material Switch Widget!**

`style.h`

```
/*
 * This is nearly complete Material design Switch widget implementation in qtwidgets module.
 * More info: https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#switches
 * Copyright (C) 2018 Iman Ahmadvand
 *
 * This is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * It is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
*/

#ifndef STYLE_H
#define STYLE_H

#include <QtCore/qeasingcurve.h>

#define cyan500 QColor("#00bcd4")
#define gray50 QColor("#fafafa")
#define black QColor("#000000")
#define gray400 QColor("#bdbdbd")

Q_DECL_IMPORT void qt_blurImage(QPainter *p, QImage &blurImage, qreal radius, bool quality, bool alphaOnly, int transposed = 0); // src/widgets/effects/qpixmapfilter.cpp

namespace Style {

    using Type = QEasingCurve::Type;

    struct Animation {
        Animation() = default;
        Animation(Type _easing, int _duration) :easing{ _easing }, duration{ _duration } {

        }

        Type easing;
        int duration;
    };

    struct Switch {
        Switch() :
            height{ 36 },
            font{ QFont("Roboto medium", 13) },
            indicatorMargin{ QMargins(8, 8, 8, 8) },
            thumbOnBrush{ cyan500 },
            thumbOnOpacity{ 1 },
            trackOnBrush{ cyan500 },
            trackOnOpacity{ 0.5 },
            thumbOffBrush{ gray50 },
            thumbOffOpacity{ 1 },
            trackOffBrush{ black },
            trackOffOpacity{ 0.38 },
            thumbDisabled{ gray400 },
            thumbDisabledOpacity{ 1 },
            trackDisabled{ black },
            trackDisabledOpacity{ 0.12 },
            textColor{ black },
            disabledTextOpacity{ 0.26 },
            thumbBrushAnimation{ Animation(Type::Linear, 150) },
            trackBrushAnimation{ Animation(Type::Linear, 150) },
            thumbPosAniamtion{ Animation(Type::InOutQuad, 150) } {

        }

        int height;
        QFont font;
        QMargins indicatorMargin;
        QColor thumbOnBrush;
        double thumbOnOpacity;
        QColor trackOnBrush;
        double trackOnOpacity;
        QColor thumbOffBrush;
        double thumbOffOpacity;
        QColor trackOffBrush;
        double trackOffOpacity;
        QColor thumbDisabled;
        double thumbDisabledOpacity;
        QColor trackDisabled;
        double trackDisabledOpacity;
        QColor textColor;
        double disabledTextOpacity;
        Animation thumbBrushAnimation;
        Animation trackBrushAnimation;
        Animation thumbPosAniamtion;
    };

    inline QPixmap drawShadowEllipse(qreal radius, qreal elevation, const QColor& color) {
        auto px = QPixmap(radius * 2, radius * 2);
        px.fill(Qt::transparent);

        { // draw ellipes
            QPainter p(&px);
            p.setBrush(color);
            p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
            p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
            p.drawEllipse(QRectF(0, 0, px.size().width(), px.size().height()).center(), radius - elevation, radius - elevation);
        }

        QImage tmp(px.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        tmp.setDevicePixelRatio(px.devicePixelRatioF());
        tmp.fill(0);
        QPainter tmpPainter(&tmp);
        tmpPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
        tmpPainter.drawPixmap(QPointF(), px);
        tmpPainter.end();

        // blur the alpha channel
        QImage blurred(tmp.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        blurred.setDevicePixelRatio(px.devicePixelRatioF());
        blurred.fill(0);
        {
            QPainter blurPainter(&blurred);
            qt_blurImage(&blurPainter, tmp, elevation * 4., true, false);
        }

        tmp = blurred;

        return QPixmap::fromImage(tmp);
    }

} // namespace Style

#endif // STYLE_H
```

`switch.h`

```
/*
 * This is nearly complete Material design Switch widget implementation in qtwidgets module.
 * More info: https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#switches
 * Copyright (C) 2018-2020 Iman Ahmadvand
 *
 * This is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * It is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
*/

#ifndef SWITCH_H
#define SWITCH_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include "style.h"

class Animator final : public QVariantAnimation {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject* targetObject READ targetObject WRITE setTargetObject)

  public:
    Animator(QObject* target, QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~Animator() override;

    QObject* targetObject() const;
    void setTargetObject(QObject* target);

    inline bool isRunning() const {
        return state() == Running;
    }

  public slots:
    void setup(int duration, QEasingCurve easing = QEasingCurve::Linear);
    void interpolate(const QVariant& start, const QVariant& end);
    void setCurrentValue(const QVariant&);

  protected:
    void updateCurrentValue(const QVariant& value) override final;
    void updateState(QAbstractAnimation::State newState, QAbstractAnimation::State oldState) override final;

  private:
    QPointer<QObject> target;
};

class SelectionControl : public QAbstractButton {
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit SelectionControl(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~SelectionControl() override;

    Qt::CheckState checkState() const;

  Q_SIGNALS:
    void stateChanged(int);

  protected:
    void enterEvent(QEvent*) override;
    void checkStateSet() override;
    void nextCheckState() override;
    virtual void toggle(Qt::CheckState state) = 0;
};

class Switch final : public SelectionControl {
    Q_OBJECT

    static constexpr auto CORNER_RADIUS = 8.0;
    static constexpr auto THUMB_RADIUS = 14.5;
    static constexpr auto SHADOW_ELEVATION = 2.0;

  public:
    explicit Switch(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    Switch(const QString& text, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    Switch(const QString& text, const QBrush&, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~Switch() override;

    QSize sizeHint() const override final;

  protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override final;
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*) override final;
    void toggle(Qt::CheckState) override final;

    void init();
    QRect indicatorRect();
    QRect textRect();

    static inline QColor colorFromOpacity(const QColor& c, qreal opacity) {
        return QColor(c.red(), c.green(), c.blue(), qRound(opacity * 255.0));
    }
    static inline bool ltr(QWidget* w) {
        if (nullptr != w)
            return w->layoutDirection() == Qt::LeftToRight;

        return false;
    }

  private:
    Style::Switch style;
    QPixmap shadowPixmap;
    QPointer<Animator> thumbBrushAnimation;
    QPointer<Animator> trackBrushAnimation;
    QPointer<Animator> thumbPosAniamtion;
};

#endif // SWITCH_H
```

`switch.cpp`

```
/*
 * This is nearly complete Material design Switch widget implementation in qtwidgets module.
 * More info: https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#switches
 * Copyright (C) 2018-2020 Iman Ahmadvand
 *
 * This is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * It is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
*/

#include "switch.h"

Animator::Animator(QObject* target, QObject* parent) : QVariantAnimation(parent) {
    setTargetObject(target);
}

Animator::~Animator() {
    stop();
}

QObject* Animator::targetObject() const {
    return target.data();
}

void Animator::setTargetObject(QObject* _target) {
    if (target.data() == _target)
        return;

    if (isRunning()) {
        qWarning("Animation::setTargetObject: you can't change the target of a running animation");
        return;
    }

    target = _target;
}

void Animator::updateCurrentValue(const QVariant& value) {
    Q_UNUSED(value);

    if (!target.isNull()) {
        auto update = QEvent(QEvent::StyleAnimationUpdate);
        update.setAccepted(false);
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent(target.data(), &update);
        if (!update.isAccepted())
            stop();
    }
}

void Animator::updateState(QAbstractAnimation::State newState, QAbstractAnimation::State oldState) {
    if (target.isNull() && oldState == Stopped) {
        qWarning("Animation::updateState: Changing state of an animation without target");
        return;
    }

    QVariantAnimation::updateState(newState, oldState);

    if (!endValue().isValid() && direction() == Forward) {
        qWarning("Animation::updateState (%s): starting an animation without end value", targetObject()->metaObject()->className());
    }
}

void Animator::setup(int duration, QEasingCurve easing) {
    setDuration(duration);
    setEasingCurve(easing);
}

void Animator::interpolate(const QVariant& _start, const QVariant& end) {
    setStartValue(_start);
    setEndValue(end);
    start();
}

void Animator::setCurrentValue(const QVariant& value) {
    setStartValue(value);
    setEndValue(value);
    updateCurrentValue(currentValue());
}



SelectionControl::SelectionControl(QWidget* parent) : QAbstractButton(parent) {
    setObjectName("SelectionControl");
    setCheckable(true);
}

SelectionControl::~SelectionControl() {

}

void SelectionControl::enterEvent(QEvent* e) {
    setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    QAbstractButton::enterEvent(e);
}

Qt::CheckState SelectionControl::checkState() const {
    return isChecked() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
}

void SelectionControl::checkStateSet() {
    const auto state = checkState();
    emit stateChanged(state);
    toggle(state);
}

void SelectionControl::nextCheckState() {
    QAbstractButton::nextCheckState();
    SelectionControl::checkStateSet();
}



void Switch::init() {
    setFont(style.font);
    setObjectName("Switch");
    /* setup animations */
    thumbBrushAnimation = new Animator{ this, this };
    trackBrushAnimation = new Animator{ this, this };
    thumbPosAniamtion = new Animator{ this, this };
    thumbPosAniamtion->setup(style.thumbPosAniamtion.duration, style.thumbPosAniamtion.easing);
    trackBrushAnimation->setup(style.trackBrushAnimation.duration, style.trackBrushAnimation.easing);
    thumbBrushAnimation->setup(style.thumbBrushAnimation.duration, style.thumbBrushAnimation.easing);
    /* set init values */
    trackBrushAnimation->setStartValue(colorFromOpacity(style.trackOffBrush, style.trackOffOpacity));
    trackBrushAnimation->setEndValue(colorFromOpacity(style.trackOffBrush, style.trackOffOpacity));
    thumbBrushAnimation->setStartValue(colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOffBrush, style.thumbOffOpacity));
    thumbBrushAnimation->setEndValue(colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOffBrush, style.thumbOffOpacity));
    /* set standard palettes */
    auto p = palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::ButtonText, style.textColor);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::ButtonText, style.textColor);
    setPalette(p);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed));
}

QRect Switch::indicatorRect() {
    const auto w = style.indicatorMargin.left() + style.height + style.indicatorMargin.right();
    return ltr(this) ? QRect(0, 0, w, style.height) : QRect(width() - w, 0, w, style.height);
}

QRect Switch::textRect() {
    const auto w = style.indicatorMargin.left() + style.height + style.indicatorMargin.right();
    return ltr(this) ? rect().marginsRemoved(QMargins(w, 0, 0, 0)) : rect().marginsRemoved(QMargins(0, 0, w, 0));
}

Switch::Switch(QWidget* parent) : SelectionControl(parent) {
    init();
}

Switch::Switch(const QString& text, QWidget* parent) : Switch(parent) {
    setText(text);
}

Switch::Switch(const QString& text, const QBrush& brush, QWidget* parent) : Switch(text, parent) {
    style.thumbOnBrush = brush.color();
    style.trackOnBrush = brush.color();
}

Switch::~Switch() {

}

QSize Switch::sizeHint() const {
    auto h = style.height;
    auto w = style.indicatorMargin.left() + style.height + style.indicatorMargin.right() + fontMetrics().width(text());

    return QSize(w, h);
}

void Switch::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
    /* for desktop usage we do not need Radial reaction */

    QPainter p(this);

    const auto _indicatorRect = indicatorRect();
    const auto _textRect = textRect();
    auto trackMargin = style.indicatorMargin;
    trackMargin.setTop(trackMargin.top() + 2);
    trackMargin.setBottom(trackMargin.bottom() + 2);
    QRectF trackRect = _indicatorRect.marginsRemoved(trackMargin);

    if (isEnabled()) {
        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        /* draw track */
        p.setBrush(trackBrushAnimation->currentValue().value<QColor>());
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        p.drawRoundedRect(trackRect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
        /* draw thumb */
        trackRect.setX(trackRect.x() - trackMargin.left() - trackMargin.right() - 2 + thumbPosAniamtion->currentValue().toInt());
        auto thumbRect = trackRect;

        if (!shadowPixmap.isNull())
            p.drawPixmap(thumbRect.center() - QPointF(THUMB_RADIUS, THUMB_RADIUS - 1.0), shadowPixmap);

        p.setBrush(thumbBrushAnimation->currentValue().value<QColor>());
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        //        qDebug() << thumbRect << thumbPosAniamtion->currentValue();
        p.drawEllipse(thumbRect.center(), THUMB_RADIUS - SHADOW_ELEVATION - 1.0, THUMB_RADIUS - SHADOW_ELEVATION - 1.0);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);

        /* draw text */
        if (text().isEmpty())
            return;

        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        p.setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::ButtonText));
        p.setFont(font());
        p.drawText(_textRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, text());
    } else {
        p.setOpacity(style.trackDisabledOpacity);
        p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        // draw track
        p.setBrush(style.trackDisabled);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        p.drawRoundedRect(trackRect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
        // draw thumb
        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        if (!isChecked())
            trackRect.setX(trackRect.x() - trackMargin.left() - trackMargin.right() - 2);
        else
            trackRect.setX(trackRect.x() + trackMargin.left() + trackMargin.right() + 2);
        auto thumbRect = trackRect;

        if (!shadowPixmap.isNull())
            p.drawPixmap(thumbRect.center() - QPointF(THUMB_RADIUS, THUMB_RADIUS - 1.0), shadowPixmap);

        p.setOpacity(1.0);
        p.setBrush(style.thumbDisabled);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        p.drawEllipse(thumbRect.center(), THUMB_RADIUS - SHADOW_ELEVATION - 1.0, THUMB_RADIUS - SHADOW_ELEVATION - 1.0);

        /* draw text */
        if (text().isEmpty())
            return;

        p.setOpacity(style.disabledTextOpacity);
        p.setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::ButtonText));
        p.setFont(font());
        p.drawText(_textRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, text());
    }
}

void Switch::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* e) {
    shadowPixmap = Style::drawShadowEllipse(THUMB_RADIUS, SHADOW_ELEVATION, QColor(0, 0, 0, 70));
    SelectionControl::resizeEvent(e);
}

void Switch::toggle(Qt::CheckState state) {
    if (state == Qt::Checked) {
        const QVariant posEnd = (style.indicatorMargin.left() + style.indicatorMargin.right() + 2) * 2;
        const QVariant thumbEnd = colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOnBrush, style.thumbOnOpacity);
        const QVariant trackEnd = colorFromOpacity(style.trackOnBrush, style.trackOnOpacity);

        if (!isVisible()) {
            thumbPosAniamtion->setCurrentValue(posEnd);
            thumbBrushAnimation->setCurrentValue(thumbEnd);
            trackBrushAnimation->setCurrentValue(trackEnd);
        } else {
            thumbPosAniamtion->interpolate(0, posEnd);
            thumbBrushAnimation->interpolate(colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOffBrush, style.thumbOffOpacity), thumbEnd);
            trackBrushAnimation->interpolate(colorFromOpacity(style.trackOffBrush, style.trackOffOpacity), trackEnd);
        }
    } else { // Qt::Unchecked
        const QVariant posEnd = 0;
        const QVariant thumbEnd = colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOffBrush, style.thumbOffOpacity);
        const QVariant trackEnd = colorFromOpacity(style.trackOffBrush, style.trackOffOpacity);

        if (!isVisible()) {
            thumbPosAniamtion->setCurrentValue(posEnd);
            thumbBrushAnimation->setCurrentValue(thumbEnd);
            trackBrushAnimation->setCurrentValue(trackEnd);
        } else {
            thumbPosAniamtion->interpolate(thumbPosAniamtion->currentValue().toInt(), posEnd);
            thumbBrushAnimation->interpolate(colorFromOpacity(style.thumbOnBrush, style.thumbOnOpacity), thumbEnd);
            trackBrushAnimation->interpolate(colorFromOpacity(style.trackOnBrush, style.trackOnOpacity), trackEnd);
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "switch.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QWidget container;
    QVBoxLayout mainLayout;
    container.setLayout(&mainLayout);

    Switch* switch1 = new Switch("SWITCH");
    mainLayout.addWidget(switch1);
    Switch* switch2 = new Switch("SWITCH");
    mainLayout.addWidget(switch2);
    switch2->setDisabled(true);
    Switch* switch3 = new Switch("SWITCH");
    mainLayout.addWidget(switch3);
    switch3->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
    Switch* switch4 = new Switch("SWITCH");
    mainLayout.addWidget(switch4);
    switch4->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
    switch4->setChecked(true);
    switch4->setDisabled(true);

    QButtonGroup bg;
    Switch* item1 = new Switch("ITEM1");
    Switch* item2 = new Switch("ITEM2");
    bg.addButton(item1);
    bg.addButton(item2);
    mainLayout.addWidget(item1);
    mainLayout.addWidget(item2);
    mainLayout.setMargin(100);

    container.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This class is great, but it needs a call to 
   `QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(e);` at the end of void `Switch::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)`.  This will help the button emit all the right signals when clicked.

Comment: Yeah it's good practice to call base class implementation.thanks

Comment: This implementation has a few issues, e.g. a missing call to QAbstractButton::setCheckable(true) (to get correct toggled/clicked signals) and the calculations don't work if the margin is 0. These are relatively easy to fix though. Because I was looking for a PyQt5 solution, I posted my fixed version as an answer as well. Thanks, INAN4K for your example!

Comment: IMAN4K your code doesn't compile with qt 6.4, getting different errors, could you take a look at it?

Comment: Changing ``void enterEvent(QEvent*) override;`` to ``void enterEvent(QEnterEvent*) override;`` and ``fontMetrics().width(text()`` to ``QFontMetrics(font()).horizontalAdvance(text())`` worked for me in Qt6.6

Comment: This also uses reserved identifiers (namely the ones beginning with a `__`), and leaks the `painter` objects in `::paintEvent`, can't see much of a reason why these aren't stack allocated or at least `std::unique_ptr<QPainter>`'s.

Answer (score 28):

A few months ago I made an implementation whose visuals needed to be more consistent with common desktop styles (C++ and Python version available; the Python version was the prototype, i.e. they might work differently). Notice that the aesthetics is fully customized using `paintEvent`. Do not expect different visuals depending on system.

[image: A switch button implementation in Qt (C++;Python)]

---

**C++ implementation**

NOTE: don't forget the includes (which are not in my example).

*Usage:*

```
SwitchButton* sbtn = new SwitchButton(this); // Default style is Style::ONOFF
bool current = sbtn->value();
sbtn->setValue(!current);
```

*(...).hpp*

```
class SwitchButton : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(SwitchButton)

public:
  enum Style
  {
    YESNO,
    ONOFF,
    BOOL,
    EMPTY
  };

public:
  explicit SwitchButton(QWidget* parent = nullptr, Style style = Style::ONOFF);
  ~SwitchButton() override;

  //-- QWidget methods
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) override;
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
  void setEnabled(bool);

  //-- Setters
  void setDuration(int);
  void setValue(bool);

  //-- Getters
  bool value() const;

signals:
  void valueChanged(bool newvalue);

private:
  class SwitchCircle;
  class SwitchBackground;
  void _update();

private:
  bool _value;
  int  _duration;

  QLinearGradient _lg;
  QLinearGradient _lg2;
  QLinearGradient _lg_disabled;

  QColor _pencolor;
  QColor _offcolor;
  QColor _oncolor;
  int    _tol;
  int    _borderradius;

  // This order for definition is important (these widgets overlap)
  QLabel*           _labeloff;
  SwitchBackground* _background;
  QLabel*           _labelon;
  SwitchCircle*     _circle;

  bool _enabled;

  QPropertyAnimation* __btn_move;
  QPropertyAnimation* __back_move;
};

class SwitchButton::SwitchBackground : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(SwitchBackground)

public:
  explicit SwitchBackground(QWidget* parent = nullptr, QColor color = QColor(154, 205, 50), bool rect = false);
  ~SwitchBackground() override;

  //-- QWidget methods
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
  void setEnabled(bool);

private:
  bool            _rect;
  int             _borderradius;
  QColor          _color;
  QColor          _pencolor;
  QLinearGradient _lg;
  QLinearGradient _lg_disabled;

  bool _enabled;
};


class SwitchButton::SwitchCircle : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(SwitchCircle)

public:
  explicit SwitchCircle(QWidget* parent = nullptr, QColor color = QColor(255, 255, 255), bool rect = false);
  ~SwitchCircle() override;

  //-- QWidget methods
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
  void setEnabled(bool);

private:
  bool            _rect;
  int             _borderradius;
  QColor          _color;
  QColor          _pencolor;
  QRadialGradient _rg;
  QLinearGradient _lg;
  QLinearGradient _lg_disabled;

  bool _enabled;
};
```

*(...).cpp*

```
SwitchButton::SwitchButton(QWidget* parent, Style style)
  : QWidget(parent)
  , _value(false)
  , _duration(100)
  , _enabled(true)
{
  _pencolor = QColor(120, 120, 120);

  _lg = QLinearGradient(35, 30, 35, 0);
  _lg.setColorAt(0, QColor(210, 210, 210));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.82, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg.setColorAt(1, QColor(210, 210, 210));

  _lg2 = QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0);
  _lg2.setColorAt(0, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg2.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg2.setColorAt(0.82, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg2.setColorAt(1, QColor(230, 230, 230));

  _lg_disabled = QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0);
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0, QColor(200, 200, 200));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.82, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(1, QColor(200, 200, 200));

  _offcolor = QColor(255, 255, 255);
  _oncolor = QColor(154, 205, 50);
  _tol = 0;
  _borderradius = 12;
  _labeloff = NEW QLabel(this);
  _background = NEW SwitchBackground(this, _oncolor);
  _labelon = NEW QLabel(this);
  _circle = NEW SwitchCircle(this, _offcolor);
  __btn_move = NEW QPropertyAnimation(this);
  __back_move = NEW QPropertyAnimation(this);

  __btn_move->setTargetObject(_circle);
  __btn_move->setPropertyName("pos");
  __back_move->setTargetObject(_background);
  __back_move->setPropertyName("size");

  setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

  _labeloff->setText("Off");
  _labelon->setText("On");
  _labeloff->move(31, 5);
  _labelon->move(15, 5);
  setFixedSize(QSize(60, 24));
  if (style == Style::YESNO)
  {
    _labeloff->setText("No");
    _labelon->setText("Yes");
    _labeloff->move(33, 5);
    _labelon->move(12, 5);
    setFixedSize(QSize(60, 24));
  }
  else if (style == Style::BOOL)
  {
    _labeloff->setText("False");
    _labelon->setText("True");
    _labeloff->move(37, 5);
    _labelon->move(12, 5);
    setFixedSize(QSize(75, 24));
  }
  if (style == Style::EMPTY)
  {
    _labeloff->setText("");
    _labelon->setText("");
    _labeloff->move(31, 5);
    _labelon->move(12, 5);
    setFixedSize(QSize(45, 24));
  }

  _labeloff->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-weight: bold;");
  _labelon->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold;");

  _background->resize(20, 20);

  _background->move(2, 2);
  _circle->move(2, 2);
}

SwitchButton::~SwitchButton()
{
  delete _circle;
  delete _background;
  delete _labeloff;
  delete _labelon;
  delete __btn_move;
  delete __back_move;
}

void SwitchButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter* painter = new QPainter;
  painter->begin(this);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

  QPen pen(Qt::NoPen);
  painter->setPen(pen);

  painter->setBrush(_pencolor);
  painter->drawRoundedRect(0, 0
    , width(), height()
    , 12, 12);

  painter->setBrush(_lg);
  painter->drawRoundedRect(1, 1
    , width() - 2, height() - 2
    , 10, 10);

  painter->setBrush(QColor(210, 210, 210));
  painter->drawRoundedRect(2, 2
    , width() - 4, height() - 4
    , 10, 10);

  if (_enabled)
  {
    painter->setBrush(_lg2);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(3, 3
      , width() - 6, height() - 6
      , 7, 7);
  }
  else
  {
    painter->setBrush(_lg_disabled);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(3, 3
      , width() - 6, height() - 6
      , 7, 7);
  }
  painter->end();
}

void SwitchButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
  if (!_enabled)
    return;

  __btn_move->stop();
  __back_move->stop();

  __btn_move->setDuration(_duration);
  __back_move->setDuration(_duration);

  int hback = 20;
  QSize initial_size(hback, hback);
  QSize final_size(width() - 4, hback);

  int xi = 2;
  int y  = 2;
  int xf = width() - 22;

  if (_value)
  {
    final_size = QSize(hback, hback);
    initial_size = QSize(width() - 4, hback);

    xi = xf;
    xf = 2;
  }

  __btn_move->setStartValue(QPoint(xi, y));
  __btn_move->setEndValue(QPoint(xf, y));

  __back_move->setStartValue(initial_size);
  __back_move->setEndValue(final_size);

  __btn_move->start();
  __back_move->start();

  // Assigning new current value
  _value = !_value;
  emit valueChanged(_value);
}

void SwitchButton::setEnabled(bool flag)
{
  _enabled = flag;
  _circle->setEnabled(flag);
  _background->setEnabled(flag);
  if (flag)
    _labelon->show();
  else
  {
    if (value())
      _labelon->show();
    else
      _labelon->hide();
  }
  QWidget::setEnabled(flag);
}

void SwitchButton::setDuration(int time)
{
  _duration = time;
}

void SwitchButton::setValue(bool flag)
{
  if (flag == value())
    return;
  else
  {
    _value = flag;
    _update();
    setEnabled(_enabled);
  }
}

bool SwitchButton::value() const
{
  return _value;
}

void SwitchButton::_update()
{
  int hback = 20;
  QSize final_size(width() - 4, hback);

  int y = 2;
  int xf = width() - 22;

  if (_value)
  {
    final_size = QSize(hback, hback);
    xf = 2;
  }

  _circle->move(QPoint(xf, y));
  _background->resize(final_size);
}

SwitchButton::SwitchBackground::SwitchBackground(QWidget* parent, QColor color, bool rect)
  : QWidget(parent)
  , _rect(rect)
  , _borderradius(12)
  , _color(color)
  , _pencolor(QColor(170, 170, 170))
{
  setFixedHeight(20);

  _lg = QLinearGradient(0, 25, 70, 0);
  _lg.setColorAt(0, QColor(154, 194, 50));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(154, 210, 50));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.95, QColor(154, 194, 50));

  _lg_disabled = QLinearGradient(0, 25, 70, 0);
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0, QColor(190, 190, 190));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.95, QColor(190, 190, 190));

  if (_rect)
    _borderradius = 0;

  _enabled = true;
}
SwitchButton::SwitchBackground::~SwitchBackground()
{
}
void SwitchButton::SwitchBackground::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter* painter = new QPainter;
  painter->begin(this);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

  QPen pen(Qt::NoPen);
  painter->setPen(pen);
  if (_enabled)
  {
    painter->setBrush(QColor(154, 190, 50));
    painter->drawRoundedRect(0, 0
      , width(), height()
      , 10, 10);

    painter->setBrush(_lg);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(1, 1, width()-2, height()-2, 8, 8);
  }
  else
  {
    painter->setBrush(QColor(150, 150, 150));
    painter->drawRoundedRect(0, 0
      , width(), height()
      , 10, 10);

    painter->setBrush(_lg_disabled);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(1, 1, width() - 2, height() - 2, 8, 8);
  }
  painter->end();
}
void SwitchButton::SwitchBackground::setEnabled(bool flag)
{
  _enabled = flag;
}

SwitchButton::SwitchCircle::SwitchCircle(QWidget* parent, QColor color, bool rect)
  : QWidget(parent)
  , _rect(rect)
  , _borderradius(12)
  , _color(color)
  , _pencolor(QColor(120, 120, 120))
{
  setFixedSize(20, 20);

  _rg = QRadialGradient(static_cast<int>(width() / 2), static_cast<int>(height() / 2), 12);
  _rg.setColorAt(0, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _rg.setColorAt(0.6, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _rg.setColorAt(1, QColor(205, 205, 205));

  _lg = QLinearGradient(3, 18, 20, 4);
  _lg.setColorAt(0, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.55, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg.setColorAt(0.72, QColor(255, 255, 255));
  _lg.setColorAt(1, QColor(255, 255, 255));

  _lg_disabled = QLinearGradient(3, 18, 20, 4);
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.55, QColor(210, 210, 210));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(0.72, QColor(230, 230, 230));
  _lg_disabled.setColorAt(1, QColor(230, 230, 230));

  _enabled = true;
}
SwitchButton::SwitchCircle::~SwitchCircle()
{
}
void SwitchButton::SwitchCircle::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter* painter = new QPainter;
  painter->begin(this);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

  QPen pen(Qt::NoPen);
  painter->setPen(pen);
  painter->setBrush(_pencolor);

  painter->drawEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20);
  painter->setBrush(_rg);
  painter->drawEllipse(1, 1, 18, 18);

  painter->setBrush(QColor(210, 210, 210));
  painter->drawEllipse(2, 2, 16, 16);

  if (_enabled)
  {
    painter->setBrush(_lg);
    painter->drawEllipse(3, 3, 14, 14);
  }
  else
  {
    painter->setBrush(_lg_disabled);
    painter->drawEllipse(3, 3, 14, 14);
  }

  painter->end();
}
void SwitchButton::SwitchCircle::setEnabled(bool flag)
{
  _enabled = flag;
}
```

---

**Python implementation (Prototype; PyQt5)**

*Usage:*

```
switchbtn = SwitchButton(self, "On", 15, "Off", 31, 60)
```

*(...).py*

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class SwitchButton(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, w1="Yes", l1=12, w2="No", l2=33, width=60):
        super(SwitchButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.__labeloff = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.__labeloff.setText(w2)
        self.__labeloff.setStyleSheet("""color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-weight: bold;""")
        self.__background  = Background(self)
        self.__labelon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.__labelon.setText(w1)
        self.__labelon.setStyleSheet("""color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold;""")
        self.__circle      = Circle(self)
        self.__circlemove  = None
        self.__ellipsemove = None
        self.__enabled     = True
        self.__duration    = 100
        self.__value       = False
        self.setFixedSize(width, 24)

        self.__background.resize(20, 20)
        self.__background.move(2, 2)
        self.__circle.move(2, 2)
        self.__labelon.move(l1, 5)
        self.__labeloff.move(l2, 5)

    def setDuration(self, time):
        self.__duration = time

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.__enabled:
            return

        self.__circlemove = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.__circle, b"pos")
        self.__circlemove.setDuration(self.__duration)

        self.__ellipsemove = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.__background, b"size")
        self.__ellipsemove.setDuration(self.__duration)

        xs = 2
        y  = 2
        xf = self.width()-22
        hback = 20
        isize = QtCore.QSize(hback, hback)
        bsize = QtCore.QSize(self.width()-4, hback)
        if self.__value:
            xf = 2
            xs = self.width()-22
            bsize = QtCore.QSize(hback, hback)
            isize = QtCore.QSize(self.width()-4, hback)

        self.__circlemove.setStartValue(QtCore.QPoint(xs, y))
        self.__circlemove.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(xf, y))

        self.__ellipsemove.setStartValue(isize)
        self.__ellipsemove.setEndValue(bsize)

        self.__circlemove.start()
        self.__ellipsemove.start()
        self.__value = not self.__value

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 12, 12)
        lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(35, 30, 35, 0)
        lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210, 255))
        qp.setBrush(lg)
        qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width()-2, s.height()-2, 10, 10)

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(2, 2, s.width() - 4, s.height() - 4, 10, 10)

        if self.__enabled:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(3, 3, s.width() - 6, s.height() - 6, 7, 7)
        else:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(3, 3, s.width() - 6, s.height() - 6, 7, 7)
        qp.end()

class Circle(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__enabled = True
        self.setFixedSize(20, 20)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        qp.drawEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20)
        rg = QtGui.QRadialGradient(int(self.width() / 2), int(self.height() / 2), 12)
        rg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        rg.setColorAt(0.6, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        rg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(205, 205, 205))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(rg))
        qp.drawEllipse(1,1, 18, 18)

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
        qp.drawEllipse(2, 2, 16, 16)

        if self.__enabled:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(3, 18,20, 4)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.55, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.72, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawEllipse(3,3, 14, 14)
        else:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(3, 18, 20, 4)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(0.55, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
            lg.setColorAt(0.72, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawEllipse(3, 3, 14, 14)
        qp.end()

class Background(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Background, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__enabled = True
        self.setFixedHeight(20)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(154,205,50))
        if self.__enabled:
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 190, 50))
            qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 10, 10)

            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 25, 70, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(154, 184, 50))
            lg.setColorAt(0.35, QtGui.QColor(154, 210, 50))
            lg.setColorAt(0.85, QtGui.QColor(154, 184, 50))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width() - 2, s.height() - 2, 8, 8)
        else:
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(150, 150, 150))
            qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 10, 10)

            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(5, 25, 60, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(190, 190, 190))
            lg.setColorAt(0.35, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(0.85, QtGui.QColor(190, 190, 190))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width() - 2, s.height() - 2, 8, 8)
        qp.end()
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is a Python 3 / PyQt5 implementation of @IMAN4K’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102598/3564517).

Improvements over the original implementation:

- Thumb-size can be larger/smaller than the track size
- Use current app’s palette for coloring
- Emit toggled/clicked signals when clicked
- Various other fixes

[image]

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QRectF, QSize, Qt, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractButton,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QSizePolicy,
    QWidget,
)


class Switch(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, track_radius=10, thumb_radius=8):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self._track_radius = track_radius
        self._thumb_radius = thumb_radius

        self._margin = max(0, self._thumb_radius - self._track_radius)
        self._base_offset = max(self._thumb_radius, self._track_radius)
        self._end_offset = {
            True: lambda: self.width() - self._base_offset,
            False: lambda: self._base_offset,
        }
        self._offset = self._base_offset

        palette = self.palette()
        if self._thumb_radius > self._track_radius:
            self._track_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.dark(),
            }
            self._thumb_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.light(),
            }
            self._text_color = {
                True: palette.highlightedText().color(),
                False: palette.dark().color(),
            }
            self._thumb_text = {
                True: '',
                False: '',
            }
            self._track_opacity = 0.5
        else:
            self._thumb_color = {
                True: palette.highlightedText(),
                False: palette.light(),
            }
            self._track_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.dark(),
            }
            self._text_color = {
                True: palette.highlight().color(),
                False: palette.dark().color(),
            }
            self._thumb_text = {
                True: '✔',
                False: '✕',
            }
            self._track_opacity = 1

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def offset(self):
        return self._offset

    @offset.setter
    def offset(self, value):
        self._offset = value
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        return QSize(
            4 * self._track_radius + 2 * self._margin,
            2 * self._track_radius + 2 * self._margin,
        )

    def setChecked(self, checked):
        super().setChecked(checked)
        self.offset = self._end_offset[checked]()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.offset = self._end_offset[self.isChecked()]()

    def paintEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name, unused-argument
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        track_opacity = self._track_opacity
        thumb_opacity = 1.0
        text_opacity = 1.0
        if self.isEnabled():
            track_brush = self._track_color[self.isChecked()]
            thumb_brush = self._thumb_color[self.isChecked()]
            text_color = self._text_color[self.isChecked()]
        else:
            track_opacity *= 0.8
            track_brush = self.palette().shadow()
            thumb_brush = self.palette().mid()
            text_color = self.palette().shadow().color()

        p.setBrush(track_brush)
        p.setOpacity(track_opacity)
        p.drawRoundedRect(
            self._margin,
            self._margin,
            self.width() - 2 * self._margin,
            self.height() - 2 * self._margin,
            self._track_radius,
            self._track_radius,
        )
        p.setBrush(thumb_brush)
        p.setOpacity(thumb_opacity)
        p.drawEllipse(
            self.offset - self._thumb_radius,
            self._base_offset - self._thumb_radius,
            2 * self._thumb_radius,
            2 * self._thumb_radius,
        )
        p.setPen(text_color)
        p.setOpacity(text_opacity)
        font = p.font()
        font.setPixelSize(1.5 * self._thumb_radius)
        p.setFont(font)
        p.drawText(
            QRectF(
                self.offset - self._thumb_radius,
                self._base_offset - self._thumb_radius,
                2 * self._thumb_radius,
                2 * self._thumb_radius,
            ),
            Qt.AlignCenter,
            self._thumb_text[self.isChecked()],
        )

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'offset', self)
            anim.setDuration(120)
            anim.setStartValue(self.offset)
            anim.setEndValue(self._end_offset[self.isChecked()]())
            anim.start()

    def enterEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        super().enterEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    # Thumb size < track size (Gitlab style)
    s1 = Switch()
    s1.toggled.connect(lambda c: print('toggled', c))
    s1.clicked.connect(lambda c: print('clicked', c))
    s1.pressed.connect(lambda: print('pressed'))
    s1.released.connect(lambda: print('released'))
    s2 = Switch()
    s2.setEnabled(False)

    # Thumb size > track size (Android style)
    s3 = Switch(thumb_radius=11, track_radius=8)
    s4 = Switch(thumb_radius=11, track_radius=8)
    s4.setEnabled(False)

    l = QHBoxLayout()
    l.addWidget(s1)
    l.addWidget(s2)
    l.addWidget(s3)
    l.addWidget(s4)
    w = QWidget()
    w.setLayout(l)
    w.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How to adapt it for PySide2 ?

Comment: How to adapt it for C++ ?

Comment: Nevermind. I reimplemented your code in C++. Thank you for this nice solution.

Comment: @stefan Is there a guide on how I can integrate this widget into Qt Designer?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I don’t use the designer.

Comment: For PySide2 (after refactoring this code) you need to establish the @pyqtProperty(int) def offset as a pyside property. The only way I've found currently is to split them into a get_offset and set_offset function. You then wrap them into a QCore.Property, the same indent as the def functions seems to be fine.
*****
    def get_offset(self):
        return self._offset
*****
    def set_offset(self, value):
        self._offset = value
        self.update()
*****
    offset = QtCore.Property(int, get_offset, set_offset)

Comment: How to adapt it for Turbo Pascal?

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this with a QSlider control in a horizontal orientation that has a range of 0 to 1.  You'd probably want to set its max width to something like 50 or so, to keep it from stretching across the width of the dialog.  You could then tweak it with a style sheet to improve the appearance, or subclass it and draw the controls yourself.  It might not take too much code to make it look good.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll have to use [QCheckBox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html). It's not a Toggle Switch, but it does same thing. If you really want different visual, you'll have to create custom widget

Answer (score 3):

Davita is right [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14780549/488657) where it concerns checkboxes. If you are looking for something similar to third example however (the on/off switches) you could simply use two [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpushbutton.html)s for that and set them to be [checkable](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop). Make them [autoexclusive](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractbutton.html#autoExclusive-prop) at the same time, and you should be good to go.

With a bit of visual styling [using a stylesheet](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/stylesheet.html) you should be able to get close, if not spot on.

Comment: Would you say arranging two PushButtons side-by-side and modifying the stylesheet would be more elegant than bringing in the QML object? I'm trying to see what would be the best way to get the equivalent look and feel of the Toggle Switch.

Comment: More elegant, I could really not tell you. I don't have a lot of experience with the QML part of Qt. The QPushbutton solution should really be trivial though, so it would be my way to go. But that's only based on my experience with Qt (the C++ side) and lack of experience with QML.

Comment: From such a switch one might expect an animated transition, which two QPushButtons don't provide. (Instead they bring their own, which would be confusing in this context)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Care to clarify? What "animated transition" would you expect? Have I missed a point somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C++ implementation of @Stefan Scherfke’s answer which is  Python 3 / PyQt5 implementation of @IMAN4K’s answer. In addition to the improvements added by Stefan Scherfke, I have also added a few improvements.

Toggle button has 2 different design according to the parameters given to the constructor function.

```
explicit ToggleButton(int trackRadius, int thumbRadius, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
```

In the first design(***trackRadius>thumbRadius***), ball (thumb) radius is smaller than the slide (track) radius, thus ball moves inside the slide according to the on/off status and includes the check “✔”  and uncheck  “✕” marks.

In the second design(***trackRadius<thumbRadius***), ball (thumb) radius is larger than the slide (track) radius, a flat fat ball slides over the track and changes color depending on the on/off situation.

[image]

I used the U+2714 Heavy Check and U+2715 unCheck marks as UTF-16 in QChar type in order not to create encoding problems in the source code.

I drew Heavy Check “✔” and Uncheck “✕” marks with the DrawPath function due to the problems of anti aliasing provided by the drawText function.

**DrawPath**:

[image]

**DrawText**:

[image]

But since the drawPath function is not capable of aligment, I calculated Pixel offsets manually based on this picture to provide aligment.

[image]

---

**ToggleButton.h**

```
#ifndef TOGGLEBUTTON_H
#define TOGGLEBUTTON_H

#include <QtWidgets/QAbstractButton>


class QPropertyAnimation;

class ToggleButton :public QAbstractButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(int mOffset READ offset WRITE setOffset);
public:
    explicit ToggleButton(int trackRadius, int thumbRadius, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~ToggleButton();

    QSize sizeHint() const override;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent  *) override;
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event) override;
    void setChecked(bool checked);

    int offset();
    void setOffset(int value);

private:
    qreal mOffset;
    qreal mBaseOffset;
    qreal mMargin;
    qreal mTrackRadius;
    qreal mThumbRadius;
    qreal mOpacity;
    QPropertyAnimation* mAnimation;

    QHash<bool, qreal> mEndOffset;
    QHash<bool, QBrush> mTrackColor;
    QHash<bool, QBrush> mThumbColor;
    QHash<bool, QColor> mTextColor;
    QHash<bool, QString> mThumbText;

};

#endif // TOGGLEBUTTON_H
```

---

**ToggleButton.cpp**

```
#include "toggleButton.h"
#include <QtCore/QEvent>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QPropertyAnimation> 
#include <QtGui/QPainter> 
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent> 

///<summary>
/// Toggle button has 2 different design. In the first design, if the ball (thumb) radius is 
/// larger than the slide (track) radius, a flat ball slides and colors from the slide according to 
/// the on / off situation. In the second design, if the ball radius is smaller than the slide radius, 
/// the ball moves according to the on / off status inside the slide and includes the check and uncheck marks.
///</summary>
ToggleButton::ToggleButton(int trackRadius, int thumbRadius, QWidget* parent)
    : QAbstractButton(parent)
{
    setCheckable(true);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed));
    mTrackRadius = trackRadius;
    mThumbRadius = thumbRadius;
    mAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(this);
    mAnimation->setTargetObject(this);

    mMargin = 0 > (mThumbRadius - mTrackRadius) ? 0 : (mThumbRadius - mTrackRadius);
    mBaseOffset = mThumbRadius > mTrackRadius ? mThumbRadius : mTrackRadius;
    mEndOffset.insert(true, 4 * mTrackRadius + 2 * mMargin - mBaseOffset); // width - offset
    mEndOffset.insert(false, mBaseOffset);
    mOffset = mBaseOffset;
    QPalette palette = this->palette();

    if (mThumbRadius > mTrackRadius)
    {
        mTrackColor.insert(true, palette.highlight());
        mTrackColor.insert(false, palette.dark());
        mThumbColor.insert(true, palette.highlight());
        mThumbColor.insert(false, palette.light());
        mTextColor.insert(true, palette.highlightedText().color());
        mTextColor.insert(false, palette.dark().color());
        mThumbText.insert(true, "");
        mThumbText.insert(false, "");
        mOpacity = 0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        mTrackColor.insert(true, palette.highlight());
        mTrackColor.insert(false, palette.dark());
        mThumbColor.insert(true, palette.highlightedText());
        mThumbColor.insert(false, palette.light());
        mTextColor.insert(true, palette.highlight().color());
        mTextColor.insert(false, palette.dark().color());
        mThumbText.insert(true, QChar(0x2714)); // check character
        mThumbText.insert(false, QChar(0x2715)); // uncheck character
        mOpacity = 1.0;
    }
}


ToggleButton::~ToggleButton()
{
    delete mAnimation;
}

QSize ToggleButton::sizeHint() const
{
    int w = 4 * mTrackRadius + 2 * mMargin;
    int h = 2 * mTrackRadius + 2 * mMargin;

    return QSize(w, h);
}

void ToggleButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    QPainter::RenderHints m_paintFlags = QPainter::RenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing |
        QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    p.setRenderHints(m_paintFlags, true);
    p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    bool check = isChecked();
    qreal trackOpacity = mOpacity;
    qreal textOpacity = 1.0;
    qreal thumbOpacity = 1.0;
    QBrush trackBrush;
    QBrush thumbBrush;
    QColor textColor;

    if (this->isEnabled())
    {

        trackBrush = mTrackColor[check];
        thumbBrush = mThumbColor[check];
        textColor = mTextColor[check];
    }
    else
    {
        trackOpacity *= 0.8;
        trackBrush = this->palette().shadow();
        thumbBrush = this->palette().mid();
        textColor = this->palette().shadow().color();
    }

    p.setBrush(trackBrush);
    p.setOpacity(trackOpacity);
    p.drawRoundedRect(mMargin, mMargin, width() - 2 * mMargin, height() - 2 * mMargin, mTrackRadius, mTrackRadius);

    p.setBrush(thumbBrush);
    p.setOpacity(thumbOpacity);
    p.drawEllipse(mOffset - mThumbRadius, mBaseOffset - mThumbRadius, 2 * mThumbRadius, 2 * mThumbRadius);

    p.setPen(textColor);
    p.setOpacity(textOpacity);
    QFont font = p.font();
    font.setPixelSize(1.5*mThumbRadius);
    p.setFont(font);


    // Since the antialiasasing provided by the drawText function is incompetent,
    // DrawPath function preferred. But since the drawPath function is not capable of aligment,
    // Pixel offsets calculated to provide aligment.
    QPainterPath textPath;
    qreal pixelOffset = (qreal)mThumbRadius * (1 - 1 / 1.414);
    textPath.addText(mOffset - mThumbRadius + pixelOffset, mBaseOffset + mThumbRadius - pixelOffset, font, mThumbText.value(check));
    p.drawPath(textPath);


    /*p.drawText(QRectF(mOffset - mThumbRadius,
        mBaseOffset - mThumbRadius,
        2 * mThumbRadius,
        2 * mThumbRadius),
        Qt::AlignCenter,
        mThumbText.value(check));*/
}

void ToggleButton::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* e)
{
    QAbstractButton::resizeEvent(e);
    mOffset = mEndOffset.value(isChecked());
}

void ToggleButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent  *e)
{
    QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        mAnimation->setDuration(120);
        mAnimation->setPropertyName("mOffset");
        mAnimation->setStartValue(mOffset);
        mAnimation->setEndValue(mEndOffset[isChecked()]);
        mAnimation->start();
    }
}

void ToggleButton::enterEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    QAbstractButton::enterEvent(event);
}

void ToggleButton::setChecked(bool checked)
{
    QAbstractButton::setChecked(checked);
    mOffset = mEndOffset.value(checked);
}

int ToggleButton::offset()
{
    return mOffset;
}

void ToggleButton::setOffset(int value)
{
    mOffset = value;
    update();
}
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include "toggleButton.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QHBoxLayout layout;
    widget->setLayout(&layout);
    ToggleButton *toggleButton1 = new ToggleButton(10, 8);
    ToggleButton *toggleButton2 = new ToggleButton(10, 12);
    layout.addWidget(toggleButton1);
    layout.addWidget(toggleButton2);
    widget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Instead the non-virtual `setChecked` you should override [`nextCheckState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#nextCheckState) instead.

Comment: Edit: Nope, using `nextCheckState()` kills the animation, idky.

Comment: It works here, but in the long run, overriding virtual functions [would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067995/1942555).

Answer (score 1):

Also see [QRadioButton](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qradiobutton.html) and [QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html) with [checkable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) and some style-sheet or custom drawing can be made like "On/off switches toggle"

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I struggled quite a bit with this particular issue despite being given a very good hint by Viv.

Anyway, I figured I'd share the solution I came up with on here, maybe it'll help someone else along the way.

```
void Switch::on_sldSwitch_actionTriggered(int action) {
    if(action != 7) ui->sldSwitch->setValue((action%2) ? 100 : 0);
}

void Switch::on_sldSwitch_sliderReleased() {
    ui->sldSwitch->setValue((ui->sldSwitch->sliderPosition() >= 50) ? 100 : 0);
}
```

A little explanation: `actionTriggered` will be called each time the slider is clicked or moved with the keyboard. When it is dragged, it will emit the signal '7'. To avoid immediate snapping, action 7 is blocked.

When moving to the right, it emits 3 while clicking and 1 while hitting 'right' (or 'down') on the keyboard, which is why we're snapping to the right when it's not an even number.

When moving left, it emits 2 or 4.

`sliderReleased()` will get called once you let go of the mouse button after dragging, however at this moment, the slider still has its old value (which tripped me up quite a bit). So, in order to get the correct position to snap to I queried `sliderPosition` instead of `value` and that's that.

I hope this helps someone.