# Best way to implement a toggle button with Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, togglebutton

What is the best way to implement a toggle button with the Qt framework ?

EDIT:

The only possibility I am aware of is the `QPushButton`. According to Qt documentation the `QPushButton::setCheckable(bool)` allows to have a on/off behavior. How to make it appear such as below ? Knowing I use Qt 5.1.1

[image]

Comment: Maybe `QPushButton::setCheckable(bool)` property makes it toggle?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html - search for "toggle" in the page

Comment: If I use such a function, how can I make my ToggleButton appear such as a toggle button ? knowing that I use Qt 5.1.1

Comment: The simplest way is to use an image. Put one for pressed and one of released.

Comment: You can set background/border images to it using stylesheets. See [pseudo states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states) for stylesheets.

Comment: If you want to make the button feel like on iOS. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780517/toggle-switch-in-qt - it involves many lines of codes and anmiation.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure for QPushButton, but for QCheckboxes, you can set an icon as a stylesheet, meaning that you can give any appearance you want to your checkbox. So your "on" image could be the icon for state "checked" and your "off" image for state "unchecked" (http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox)