# How to put a QLabel in a toggle button Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

For my project, I wish to have a toggle button.
After much research I found this post. [toggle-switch-in-qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780517/toggle-switch-in-qt/38102598)

I implemented the code of the third post on the link above.

This code works correctly. By cons I do not understand how can we add QLabel for the two states of the toggle button?
Would anyone have an idea to do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to draw the label manually in `Switch::paintEvent`, depending on `isEnabled()`, using [`QPainter::drawText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText). Since the paint event of the control you refer to is overridden, the default behavior in `QAbstractButton::paintEvent` which normally draws the button label is not executed.

Comment: I tried in the PaintEvent method to do p-> drawText (QRect, Qt :: AlignCenter, "name); But there is nothing that appears ....

Comment: Are you sure you are not drawing over the text? Is the text drawn at the right coordinates? Try to draw the text *after* drawing the control itself, and draw it at `QRect(margin_, margin_)`. Also make sure you use a color that will be visible by setting the right pen and brush.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your message. in isEnabled () I do :        QRect rect(0,0,_margin, _margin);
        QPen penHText(Qt::black);
        p.setPen(penHText);
        p.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignHCenter, "myText"); but it does not show anything. Yet even if the coordinates are not correct I should see my text appear ...?

Comment: What about: `drawText(QPointF(0, 10), "Some text")`, *after* all the other draw calls?