# What's virtual operator new/delete?

Tags: c++, llvm, reverse-engineering, pdb, pdb-files

Recently, I disassembled some DLL&PDB with `llvm-pdbutil pretty --classes`. But I don't have the source codes for this DLL.

In the output, I found some expressions in class body, mainly declarations of virtual operator new/delete which I'm not familar with. For example, in 2 classes, I found

```cpp
// class 1
virtual void *operator new() = 0;
virtual void operator delete() = 0;

// class 2
virtual void *operator new(unsigned __int64 Size) = 0;
virtual void operator delete(void *result) = 0;
```

I don't know what are these and what may be the correspond C++ code for them, could somebody tell me more about them?

I tried copy and paste them directly into IDE, but the linting says "only nonstatic member functions may be virtual"; if I remove 'virtual', I got "pure specifier ('= 0') allowed only on virtual functions". So the compilation won't succeed.

I'm sure that the DLL is built with VS 2019, msvc on an x86_64 machine.

---

Appended:

I dived into the source codes of llvm-pdbutil 17.0.6, and found these functions are tagged virtual or even pure virtual because that the PDBSymbol is returns to be pure in `get_pure` in DIA SDK.

```cpp
bool DIARawSymbol::isPureVirtual() const {
  return PrivateGetDIAValue(Symbol, &IDiaSymbol::get_pure);
}
```

But why? [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiasymbol-get-pure?view=vs-2022) says nothing about the definition of `pure` in this SDK.

Comment: `virtual` functions must be non-static members of a class/struct, just as the error message says. They cannot be free functions. The `= 0` specifies that the function is "pure virtual" which essentially means that some derived class must implement the functions---without an implementation, the class/struct cannot be instantiated.

Comment: C++ class-specific overloads of `operator new()` and `operator delete()` are static, so cannot be virtual.     There may be some compiler-specific or system-specific machinery involved in what you are seeing, but that is outside the scope of standard C++.

Comment: I concur, this looks suspiciously like compiler-specific machinery. Do all classes exhibit these weird operators? If not, can you induce a common trait on classes that do?

Comment: @Peter I guess maybe in the source code, these functions are not declared virtual or pure virtual, it's something about PDB..

Comment: @YSC Yes, many classes have these functions, all tagged pure virtual, with 0, 1, or 2 arguments, there are even 2 classes output more than 5 such function in class body. Maybe those classes have overloaded operator new and delete in the source code, I guess.

Comment: @猫宮かさね  ... or related to how the `llvm-pdbutil` tool presents/massages/interprets/formats data that is in the PDB format.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `virtual type function-id (argument-list) = 0;` can exist only inside of definition of class-type and explicitly tells that there is no code for it by `= 0`, thus it's called pure in C++, SDK is not related to it.

If a class `T` contains any pure member, it is called "abstract class" and cannot be constructed, therefore there cannot be an object or variable, or returned value of type `T`. There can be a pointer to `T`, or reference to `T` (`T*`, `T&` or `T&&`), but they would refer to an object of an non-abstract type derived from `T`.

A derived class should implement - override - member `function-id` with an equivalent signature. Overriding implementation doesn't require word `virtual`, although modern style is add keyword `override`:

```
  // This code is not ISO-compliant!

  struct Base {
     virtual void *operator new() =  0;   
     virtual void *operator new(unsigned __int64 Size) = 0; // new[]
   };

   struct Derived : Base {
      void *operator new() override; // override is optional
      void *operator new(unsigned __int64 Size) override; // new[]
   };
```

I assume tht there is matching `operator delete`.

Now for the fun part - disassembler had generated a non-standard code. While some compilers support virtual operator new\delete used in combination with type erasure, ISO-C++ states that these operators are implicitly `static`. I don't remeber if MS compiler supports that in any mode though, conformance mode flag (`/permissive`) might be the key, if it does.

Answer (score -2):

This is actually an overload of delete and new operators, you can do that in C++. You can read more about that here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new. " =0 " after virtual means that the class is abstract and you are not able to create it([C++ difference between virtual = 0; and empty function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075581/c-difference-between-virtual-0-and-empty-function))

Comment: In C++, `operator new()` and `operator delete()` can be overloaded (or replaced) either globally or for specific classes.   However, when replaced for specific classes, they are implicitly `static` so cannot be `virtual` (which means they can't be pure virtual).