# C++ type checking error

Tags: c++, types, c++98

I've followed the instructions I got from my last post and re-wrote my code.

My header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "Tour.h"
#include "GuidedTour.h"

using namespace std;
class TourManager {

private:
    vector<Tour *> tours;
    void setupTour();
    string getUserInput();
    string displayMainMenu();
    void displayTourDetails();
    void callDisplayOnEach();
    void addBookingsToTour();

public:
    TourManager();
    void go();
};
```

Then I have a function to populate the "list" vector with tour and guidedTour objects.

```
void TourManager::setupTour() {

    tours.push_back(new Tour("FP001", "Fun Park 3 Day Pass", 110.00));
    tours.push_back(new GuidedTour("SK003", "Learn to Ski Adventure Tour", 240.00, "28/07
}

void TourManager::callDisplayOnEach() {

    for (vector<Tour *>::iterator it = tours.begin() ; it != tours.end(); ++it) 
    {
        if(typeid(*it) == typeid(GuidedTour)) 
        {    
            cout << "Guided Tour" << "\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "NOT Guided Tour : " << typeid(*it).name() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

However I always seems to be getting back Tour objects. EG: it always prints NOT Guided Tour.

how do I archive polymorphic behavior?

Can you please advice? (I'm new to C++)
My required to use C++98

Many thanks

Comment: This is because of vector<Tour *> type. Keep seperate vector list for adding guidedtour objects.

Comment: Yes, you have a list of pointers to Tour objects...hence referencing the list will always yield a Tour*. Shouldn't be pushing GuidedTour* on there - compiler will try to cast them to Tour* and that means trouble later on.

Comment: It's for a school assignment, I'm required to use a single vector and retrieve values from it

Comment: how do I archive polymorphic behavior? thanks

Comment: @HvS: Sure, the compiler will convert the _pointer_. It will not convert what the pointer points _to_. That is and remains a `GuidedTour` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how polymorphism works.

**How to achieve what you are trying to do**

`dynamic_cast<T>` uses RTTI to check whether a polymorphic type is actually of type `T`:

```
GuidedTour * ptr = dynamic_cast<GuidedTour *>(*it);
if(ptr != NULL)
{
    std::cout << "This is a guided tour" << '\n';
}
```

However, RTTI comes at a cost; those are checks performed at runtime and will slow down your performance, and RTTI may not be supported at all.

**What you usually should do**

Avoid needing to know the exact type of your polymorphic object. Provide an interface that works well regardless and rely on calling your virtual methods to do the job.

```
class Tour
{
    public:
        virtual ~Tour() {}

        virtual void info() const
        {
            std::cout << "This is not a guided tour" << '\n';
        }
};

class GuidedTour : public Tour
{
    public:
        void info() const
        {
            std::cout << "This is a guided tour" << '\n';
        }
};

Tour * tour = new GuidedTour();
tour->info();
delete tour; // here you need the virtual destructor
```

And while we're at best practice; please avoid raw pointers. Even if you are bound to C++98, there are very good smartpointers out there; Boost for example provides `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` that closely resemble the ones in C++11.

Comment: I have displayDetails method in Tour object. It's over written in GuidedTour object. How do I call these methods without casting it? sorry I'm new to C++ and points

Comment: could you please explain this line?   virtual ~Tour() {}

Comment: @Archie I've updated my answer to show you how to call the function; explaining the `virtual` keyword would really bloat this answer, but you can find good explanations on SO, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors