# C++, missing vtable compilation error

Tags: c++

I created an interface (only .hpp file):

```
struct IA
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
};
```

and a class implementing this interface (.hpp)

```
class A : public IA
{
    virtual void foo();
}
```

and .cpp

```
void A::foo(){...}
```

this compiles without a problem, but
when I use

```
IA a;
```

in another file I get this compilation error:
"vtable for IA, referenced from: IA::IA() in libSomeOtherFile.a(SomeOtherFile.o) Note: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition" anyone know why and how do I fix that ?

Comment: Make `IA::foo()` have an empty body `{ }`.

Comment: Didn't you notice that you can eliminate `class A` entirely, and the error persists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to make an *interface*, then you should not be creating an instance of the interface type directly. Use a pointer instead:

```
IA *a = new A();
```

Additionally, if it isn't meant to be instantiated then you should make `foo` pure-virtual in `IA`:

```
/* In IA */
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

Comment: It worked :)
Once I added the = 0 to interface methods I can compile new A();
can anyone please explain why ?

Comment: Quite simply, it works because you are no longer promising to provide an implementation that doesn't exist; instead, now you are telling your compiler explicitly that the implementation won't be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead.

```
struct IA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() { }
};
```

`IA:foo` is not a [pure virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained) function and thus must have an implementation if it's to be overridden in child classes.