# Undefined reference to Base::run();

Tags: c++, gcc, dictionary

I have class Base with method const char** run, defined with no contents,
and I have class Derived with method const char** run.
I have the following code:

```
class Base { // in 'base.h'
    public:
        const char** run();
};
class Derived : public Base { // in 'derived.h'
    public:
        const char** run();
};
const char** Wsiv::run(){ // in 'derived.cpp'
    return something;
};
// IN 'main.cpp':
map<string, unique_ptr<Base>> modules;
modules["drvd"] = (unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived()));
// A little bit later...
string command = argv[1];
result = (*modules[command].get()).run();
```

Instead of executing the run() function and storing the `const char**` output to 'result', the program does not eve compile, and mingw g++ gives me this error:

```
C:/Users/bob/AppData/Local/Temp/ccc0cwsT.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4ee): Undefined reference to 'Base::run()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compile command is as follows:

```
g++ ../src/*.cpp -o test -std=c++11
```

Comment: What's `command`? Where's your code for `Base` or `Base::run()`? Which implementation of `unique_ptr` is it? Your own? Boosts? Not enough information is here to answer your question.

Comment: One question: is `Base::run` **pure** virtual ?

Comment: Provide complete code reduced to the bare minimum.

Comment: Make it pure virtual in `Base`: `virtual const char** run() = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually *defined* what `run()` does; you've only *declared* it.

In your example, you define `Wsiv::run()` which doesn't implement `Base::run()` *or* `Derived::run()`. If you meant for `Base::run()` to be implemented in a sub-class, you have to tell the compiler to look elsewhere for its definition.

This is where [virtuals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) come into play.

```
virtual const char** run() {};
```

The above says *I might be implemented in a subclass, but I have a default implementation*.

```
virtual const char** run() = 0;
```

The above, called a [pure virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained), says *I **must** be implemented in a subclass; I **do not** have a default implementation; until I'm implemented somewhere (in a subclass, for example), I am undefined*.

---

Since your example has neither, the compiler doesn't know where to jump to when `Base::run()` is called. Either define it, or declare it as a virtual.

Comment: Not "I do not have" but "I might not have"

Comment: Pure virtuals do not have a *default* implementation @Deduplicator, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: It's standard-practice to give them one, especially for dtors.

Comment: @Deduplicator where is it "standard practice" to give **pure virtuals** an implementation? That's what makes them **pure virtuals**. You're right; you don't make dtors pure virtual; you make them virtual with *default implementations* - that is standard practice.

Comment: Whenever you want to make a class abstract but don't have another function for which you a) don't want to provide a default and b) want to force overriding. If you don't give it an implementation, all derived classes will be abstract too.

Comment: ... I'm confused as to what you're trying to argue. Pure virtuals are vtable entries that, until explicitly implemented by a subclass, are for all intents and purposes a *null pointer* in the vtable. C++ doesn't have abstract classes. Unimplemented pure virtuals do not have a definition, thus the linker complains. Not sure what's being miscommunicated here...

Comment: Classes with pure virtual functions (inherited or not) are called abstract. But pure virtual functions can have a definition even though they are pure virtual, very useful for dtors (as a special case of a function which *has* to delegate to the base-class-version). And the C++ standard never talks about vtables, using a virtual where the appropriate fuction is pure virtual is just UB.

Comment: I never said the spec employs vtables; however, that's how most major compilers decide to implement virtuals (namely GCC, which is what the OP is using to compile). `But pure virtual functions can have a definition even though they are pure virtual` [No, they can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained). Not until they are **implemented**. If they have an implementation, they are simply virtual, not *pure* virtual.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc168d0e9ba6cb3 Also, where in the accepted answer does it state that a pure virtual function must not only be implemented by all non-abstract derived classes, but theat the base-class is prohibited from defining it itself?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure - you defined it. `= 0` makes it pure virtual - it doesn't have a default definition. You *gave* it a definition later, which turns it into a virtual. The declaration is a pure virtual, and you later gave it a definition. You're welcome to take this to chat, but this is a semantic rabbit hole of an argument.

Comment: Just for you, I clarified my explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Qix you seem to be overlooking the fact that *pure virtual* functions can have an implementation.