# Add things to the Update method of parent class

Tags: c++, class, parent-child

I have two classes:

```
class Object {
public: void Update();
};

class Cube : public Object {
void Update();
};
```

I want a Update() method that does everything I tell it, then does everything the Update from the parent class does. Can I do that ?

Comment: Yes you can call functions in parent classes by using the scope operator `::`.

Comment: in Cube's Update() call `Object::Update();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to change your design a little bit. 
Something like this could do what you want:

```
class Object {
public: 
    void Update(
        // invoke method from derived
        onUpdate();

        // do stuff in base
    );

protected:
    virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};

class Cube : public Object {
    void onUpdate() {
        // do stuff in derived
    }
};
```

Comment: What does the `= 0` in `virtual void onUpdate() = 0;` do ?

Comment: It means the method is "pure virtual". Adding pure virtual methods to a class make it an abstract class, meaning it cannot be instantiated.
Have a look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained

Comment: If there is nothing unclear anymore, please accept the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write `Object::update()` in Cube's update function but it is generally considered bad practice to redefine an inherited non-virtual function so I suggest you also make `update` virtual

```
class Object {
  public:
    virtual void update(){ /* ... */ }
};

class Cube : public Object {
  public:
    void update() override {
        // ...
        Object::update(); 
    }
};
```