# Direct2d ID2D1HwndRenderTarget->GetSize() returns zero

Tags: direct2d

I've noticed that calling GetSize() on ID2D1HwndRenderTarget returns 0,0 if this call is made after a BeginDraw() call.  It returns the correct value otherwise.

Is this "normal" behaviour?  I haven't seen it documented in any examples.  I did spend a few hours scratching my head over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour.

In your case, the method returns its const defined return value.

[`virtual D2D1_SIZE_F GetSize() const = 0;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316823(v=vs.85).aspx)

Most probably, the method fails inside, because the render target could not be "acquired" inside a `BeginDraw/EndDraw` loop.

> BeginDraw and EndDraw are used to indicate that a render target is in
>   use by the Direct2D system. Different implementations of
>   ID2D1RenderTarget might behave differently when BeginDraw is called.
>   An ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget may be locked between BeginDraw/EndDraw
>   calls, a DXGI surface render target might be acquired on BeginDraw and
>   released on EndDraw, while an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget may begin batching
>   at BeginDraw and may present on EndDraw, for example.

Remarks section:
[ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The "= 0" at the end of the declaration of GetSize isn't a default return value. It indicates that the member is [pure virtual](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1306837/1396177).