# C++ Abstract Class error on Constructor in Qt 5

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class, qt5

I'm creating a simple abstract class named Asset, the header code looks like this:

```
#ifndef ASSET_H
#define ASSET_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDate>

class Asset
{  
public:
    Asset(QString des, QDate dat);
    ~Asset();
    virtual QString toString();
    virtual double value();
    QString getDescription();

private:
    QString description;

protected:
    QDate date;
};

#endif // ASSET_H
```

This is what my implementation file looks like:

```
#include "asset.h"

Asset::Asset(QString des, QDate dat)
{
    description = des;
    date = dat;
}

QString Asset::getDescription()
{
    return description;
}
```

The error code I'm getting on the implementation constructor is: `undefined reference to vtable for Asset`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods you do not implement in the abstract class, should be pure `virtual` methods. That mean they should be followed by `= 0`.

For example:

```
virtual double value() = 0;
```

This tells the compiler that this is a pure virtual method. For an explanation of the difference between virtual methods and pure virtual methods, take a look at this Stackoverflow answer: [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)

On a side note. When you have an abstract class, you should really make sure that your destructor is virtual. Always use virtual destructors in C++ when you deal with class that you intend to be inherited from.

In your class design you have a private member called description, and a public function to get the description that is not virtual. You have no methods to set the description, perhaps you should consider moving the description member variable from `private` to `protected` or perhaps even creating a mutator function to set it.