# (Re-edited now, not duplicate) Why some virtual member functions don't use virtual keyword?

Tags: c++, function, constants, virtual, abstract

I have been told that if the decleration of a class member function starts with a `virtual` keyword and ends with `=0`, then this function would be a virtual function and the class it belongs to would be an abstract class (all member functions are virtual function, then would be an interface). But I also found that some classes are declared with `const=0`, but no `virtual` keyword.

So I want to know if the following two class are the same? If so, why some use `virtual` while others not. If not, then what are their differences?

```
class class1 {
   int function1() const = 0;
   int function2() const = 0;
   ...
};

class class2 {
    virtual int function1() const = 0;
    virtual int function2() const = 0;
};
```

Comment: @David Also look up what `const` means here.

Answer (score 1):

Pure virtual function, is a function that you want to override and use in derived classes. The syntax is:

```
return_type func_name (param_list) = 0;
```

This makes your function pure virtual and your class abstract. The class that contains such a function couldn't be instantiated and the function can't have a body.

`const` means that this function can not modify any other members of the class containing it.

Comment: Hi, @simplicis, I have fixed this question, could you please take a look at it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: As it is now, the aforementioned apply to `class2`. For the `class1`, I can't say anything because I haven't seen such syntax (`int func() = 0`, without `virtual` keyword) being used and I doubt that it is valid.

Comment: Hi, @simplicis, I added a picture where I found this syntax. Could you take a look? It is from a scientific computation lecture slide, I don't think he is wrong in wrting this.

Answer (score 0):

`= 0` means that the method is [pure virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306837/1870760).

This means that the class can't be instantiated and classes that inherit from that class have to provide an implementation for the method, otherwise those classes will be virtual too ( and can't be instantiated ).

Comment: but it has no `virtual` keyword.