# Don't override the pure virtual function in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In the following example, the class **Base** is an **abstract class**. the **Derived** class inherits from a **Base** class. I don't override the pure virtual function in derived class.
Then, I have been trying to create derived class object, but the compiler gives following error.

```
error: cannot declare variable 'd' to be of abstract type 'Derived'
     Derived d;
```

**Code here:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{

};

int main(void)
{
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

**Why Derived class also become abstract class?**

Comment: Yes. The `show` function will be abstract until you define it.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: I don't feel this question demonstrates any research or thought about the problem. How can `Derived` _not_ be abstract? i.e. if it wasn't, what would happen when someone thinking they had a `Base` tried to call `show()` on it? Nothing good, if somehow the compiler allowed it.

Comment: @Stefan Not my downvote but your question is "Is Derived class also become abstract class?" and the compiler error message is: "cannot declare variable 'd' to be of abstract type 'Derived'" seems to me like the compiler answered it for you.

Comment: As a sidenote `int main(){ }` is enough. No need for the `void` nor the `return 0;`.

Comment: @Ron I would argue that explicitly writing `return 0;` is good style; omitting it is only allowed because so many people couldn't be bothered to type it that the Committee buckled to make such code well-formed, AFAICT. But yes, that's not how to idiomatically write empty argument lists.

Comment: I would imagine any half-decent C++ tutorial/book would cover this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Derived` is an abstract class. This is because there is a pure virtual method `show` in the `Base` class that has been inherited by `Derived` but never resolved. This means that in order for `Derived` to become a concrete class, you must first implement a `show` method either in the `Base` class itself, or in `Derived`.

Comment: Just a minor quibble over terminology: `Derived` is not "in a way" an abstract class; it simply **is** an abstract class, because it has a pure virtual function that has not been overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A pure virtual function *must* be implemented in derived classes, or else they remain abstract classes: [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)