# Inheritance of a Pure Virtual Function

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Could somebody please clear these concepts and answer these questions. Thank you in advance.

Class A is a base class and has a pure virtual function named display.

```
class A 
{ 
  public:
       virtual void display()const=0;

};
```

Class B is a derived class that inherits the A class. Furthermore, B overrides the display function,

```
class B:public A 
{ 
  public:
       void display()const{cout<<"Always"<<endl;}

};
```

Q1: Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display, right? Or does the pure virtual one become non-existent due to the override.

I'm asking this because the ultimate question I'm facing is this:
Q2: Suppose B did override the display function, Now, if there a new class

```
class C:public B 
{ 
  public:
};
```

Now, I'm clear on the concept that the all the first level derived classes (like B) have a must on them that they override the pure virtual function(coming from the class A), suppose that they do override it, now what if the there is a new class C that is derived from one of the first-level-derived classes ( class B ), will it also need to override the pure virtual function (display) or will it be not required as it was overridden in the class B and C inherits B(consequently receiving an override of the the display function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)

Comment: @MitchWheat I read the whole thread man, I couldn't find an absolute and to-the-point answer for my question anywhere in it.

Comment: it will not be required as it was overridden in the class B and C inherits B

Comment: The confusion may come from how you are looking at this. `Class A` is an *Abstract Base Class*  because it contains at least 1 *Pure Virtual Function* declared without definition using `=0` instead. As such, `Class A` cannot be instantiated, but only inherited from. The derived class must override the pure virtual function. Once the derived class does that -- it is simply a class itself. It no longer has the constraint of being an *abstract base class* (it isn't) so it may be inherited from just as any class may be inherited from with the normal rules of access, etc..

Comment: A well-known use for Abstract Classes is [Interfaces](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm). If you google on that, you get more info.

Comment: The "first level" `B` doesn't have to override *all* pure virtual functions, it can leave some of them for further derived classes to override. That way `B` would also be abstract, just like `A`.

Comment: >> Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display.<< Wrong. It contains virtual member function  `void display() const`  that overrides abstract virtual function from class A. Note: "method" and "pure" not quite correct term in C++. Mostly because there are static member functions that ARE NOT methods in OOP meaning of it. Also operators aren't methods , but they can be members.

Comment: @AhmedMustafaMalik feel free to accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose there is a virtual base class `A`

```
class A 
{ 
  public:
       virtual void display()const=0;

};
```

.

```
class B:public A 
{ 
  public:
       void display()const{cout<<"Always"<<endl;}

};
```

> Q1: Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display, right? Or does the pure virtual one become non-existent due to the override.

Inheritance of functions is replacement. As you say, the base class function becomes non-existent in the derived class. This is true whether or not the base class function is virtual or not.

> Q2: Suppose B did override the display function, Now, if there a new class `C`

```
class C : public B 
{ 
    ...
};
```

> will it also need to override the pure virtual function (display)?

No, `C` gets all the functions from B, including the concrete implementation of `display()`

However, `C` may *optionally* override the `display()` function again. And so on and so forth. There is no limit on how many times a class can be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display, right?

I don't know what you mean by that.

`C` doesn't need to override `display`. If it doesn't, it will just use the one inherited from `B`.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display, right? Or does the pure virtual one become non-existent due to the override.

Your first question here is meaningless.    The class `B` inherits a pure virtual from `A`, and overrides it.    It does not "contain" either.

`A::display()` does actually exist, as a validly named entity that can be referred to within `B`.    For example, if `A::display()` is defined;

```
class A 
{ 
    public:
        virtual void display()const=0;
};

//   yes, defining a pure virtual function is allowed, albeit optional 
void A::display() const       
{
    std::cout << "A!\n";
}
```

then `B::display()` can call it.

```
class B:public A 
{ 
   public:
       void display()const
       {
           A::display();
           std::cout<<"Always"<<endl;
       }
};
```

so both `A::display()` and `B::display()` exist in this case.    The above code for `B::display()` will compile (since the compiler recognises both `A::display()` and `B::display()` as distinct names of functions) regardless of whether `A::display()` is defined or not.      (If `A::display()` is not defined, the linker will typically report a missing symbol).

> Q2: Suppose B did override the display function, Now, if there a new class
>
> ```
> class C:public B 
> { 
>     public:
> };
> ```
>
> Now, I'm clear on the concept that the all the first level derived classes (like B) have a must on them that they override the pure virtual function(coming from the class A), suppose that they do override it, now what if the there is a new class C that is derived from one of the first-level-derived classes ( class B ), will it also need to override the pure virtual function (display) or will it be not required as it was overridden in the class B and C inherits B(consequently receiving an override of the the display function?

If `B` has overridden `display()`, then `C` inherits `display()` as a non-pure virtual function.    This means that, if `B` can be instantiated, then so can `C`.

If `C` does not override the inherited `display()`, then `some_c->display()` will call the version inherited from `B`   i.e. `B::display()`.

If `C` does override `display()`  - which is permitted with any inherited virtual function - then it can implement `C::display()` in any way needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Now B contains 1 overridden display and 1 inherited pure virtual display, right?

NO.

You can understand it like this:

> Or does the pure virtual one become non-existent due to the override.

When you declare a function virtual then a virtual (function) table is added (to the classes) which holds function pointers to virtual functions. Whenever a override function is declared it replaces the function pointer in the virtual table.

If `B` override's the function then it's function pointer goes in the virtual table.

`C` doesn't have to override. It will get the function from `B`.

`C` can override the function. Then it's pointer will go into the virtual table.

`B`  doesn't have to override. But then a variable cannot be created of `B`. Then `C` should override the function (if you want a variable)