# What does void Enter() = 0; mean in C#?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, void

I was reading a book when I saw virtual void enter()=0;
What does the asignment do while it is not a variable?

```
class MapSite { 
public: 
virtual void Enter() = 0; 
};
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything and wouldn't compile anyway, maybe you need to recheck the language you are working in

Comment: What language? That isn't C# that would compile.

Comment: [Pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1306778/107625) in C++.

Comment: @UweKeim: Edits are not allowed to change the intent of the question.  OP's intent, apparently, was to make this understandable to a C# programmer who mistakenly believes it is C#.  Changing the tag completely loses that aspect of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code is not C#, it is C++, and is the equivalent to C#

```
abstract class MapSite
{
    public abstract void Enter();
}
```

It makes the function pure virtual, and the class abstract.  Subclasses will be abstract as well unless they provide a definition for the member function `void Enter()`

Comment: I'm wondering if I was right to mark it a dupe, since your point about being confused about the language is likely correct.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I'm inclined to take a wait-and-see approach.  If OP thinks it is different, he can let us know that opinion and then we can undo the dupe.