# How do I optimise c++ legacy boiler plate code?

Tags: c++

I am a Java user trying my hand at c++.

In the below legacy code, I have multiple derived classes.

The contents of the map in each derived class are similar differing by just a few.

The function pr() is repetitive.

I would like to optimize such piece of code.

Do let me know ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
#include <memory>


class X {
public:
    virtual void pr ()=0;

};



class Y: public X {
        std::map<string,int> fm{ {"mem1", 33},
                                 {"mem2", 44},
                                 {"YYY", 999}};

public:
    virtual void pr () {
        for(auto const &[k,v] : fm)
        {
             std::cout<<k <<"  :  "<<v <<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

class Z: public X {
    sstd::map<string,int> fm{ {"mem1", 33},
                              {"mem2", 44},
                              {"ZZZ", 777}};

public:
    virtual void pr () {
        for(auto const &[k,v] : fm)
        {
            std::cout<<k <<"  :  "<<v <<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

void fn(std::unique_ptr<X> x)
{
    x->pr();  
}

int main()
{
   fn(std::make_unique<Y>());
}
```

Comment: TBH, the one solution that strikes would be the same as in Java: Make `X::pr` non-abstract, move the definition  from derived classes to `X`, move `fm` to X as well and either initialize it with default value and modify in derived classes constructor or create `X` constructor that receives ready-made map.

Comment: "optimize" is extremely vague. I suppose you want to reduce repetition of similar code, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not called optimization. This is called refactoring code to make use of inheritance. Apparently, in your code, repetition is in data member `fm` and `pr()` function definition.

If your both classes have them in common, you can just move `pr` function definition and data member `fm` to base class so that you do not have to rewrite. Then you can initialize value of `fm`, which is only difference between two classes.  `=0` makes a [virtual function pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/virtual-pure-virtual-explained), which should be overriden by all inheriting classes. In this case, they do not override, instead they reuse `pr` function, so pure function is not needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class X {
public:
    virtual void pr (){
         for(const auto item : fm)
        {
             std::cout<<item.first <<"  :  "<<item.second <<std::endl;
        }
    };
    protected:
    std::map<string,int> fm;
};



class Y: public X 
{
    public:
    Y(){
      fm =   { {"mem1", 33},
             {"mem2", 44},
             {"YYY", 999}};
    }
};

class Z: public X 
{
    public:
    Z(){
      fm =   { {"mem1", 33},
                              {"mem2", 44},
                              {"ZZZ", 777}};
    }
};

void fn(std::unique_ptr<X> x)
{
    x->pr();  
}

int main()
{
   fn(std::make_unique<Y>());
      fn(std::make_unique<Z>());

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you change and why did you change it?

Comment: you should initialize the map in the constructors member initializer list

Answer (score 2):

I would drop the derived classes, you only have a difference in construction.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class X {
    std::map<string,int> fm;
public:
    X(std::map<string,int> fm): fm(std::move(fm)) {}
    void pr () {
        for(auto const &[k,v] : fm)
        {
             std::cout<<k <<"  :  "<<v <<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

X Y(){ return X({ {"mem1", 33}, {"mem2", 44}, {"YYY", 999}}); }
X Z(){ return X({ {"mem1", 33}, {"mem2", 44}, {"ZZZ", 777}}); }

int main()
{
    Y().pr();
}
```